# Why would a while loop be prevented from ending when using an unrelated macro?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am programming an opengl application in c++ and recently came across a problem when use a custom debugging macro. When I use the macro, the Main loop hangs when it is trying to end the loop and the program will not end properly when I close the window. As far as I can tell, the macro should not affect the ending of the loop, but when I edit the macro so that it does nothing the while loop ends as expected. I have already tested that the `glfwWindowShouldClose()` does return the expected value and that it makes it to the end of the loop when it does. The problem is when it reaches the end of the loop it will not jump out of the loop and just hangs. Here is the affected code.

The while loop currently just in the main function...

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window.getWindow()))
{
    GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));
    vertexBuffer.bind();
    indexBuffer.bind();
    shader.bind();
    shader.setUniformMat4("projection", projection);
    shader.setUniformMat4("translation", translation);

    GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
    glfwSwapBuffers(window.getWindow());

    glfwPollEvents();
}

glfwTerminate();
```

and the macro...

```
#define ASSERT(x) if(!x) __debugbreak()
#define GLCall(x) Engine::clearGLError(); x; ASSERT(Engine::logGlError(__LINE__, __FILE__))

namespace Engine {
    void clearGLError()
    {
        while (glGetError() != 0);
    }
    int logGlError(const int& lineNumber, const std::string& fileName)
    {
        int error = glGetError();
        if (error != 0) 
            Console::TextUtils::errorText("Opengl error on line: " + std::to_string(lineNumber) + " in " + fileName + " Code:" + std::to_string(error));
        return error == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: best guess: the WindowShouldClose function depends on the GLError -- calling clearGLError in the macro causes it to be lost, resulting in the function never returning true and exiting the loop.  But as you don't show that code, its impossible to tell.

Comment: @Chris Dodd I will post that code, but I don't think that is the problem as if you put windowShouldClose() at the end of the loop it does return true.

Comment: Mmmm... Lack of a semicolon after `__debugbreak()`? Also, better if you enclose `GLCall` definiton with `{}`. And `(x);` instead of `x;`

Comment: @Ripi2 Yeah I left it out since there will always be  a ";" after the function call using `ASSERT`. Thanks for the other suggestions though.

Comment: Why don't you just use a debugger? Loops don't just "hang". My suspicion would be that your `glGetError()` loop just turns into an endless loop - yes, there are circumstances where this could happen.

Comment: @derhass that was my suspicion as well, but it makes it to the end of the main loop and then the `glGetError()` should not be called again before the loop breaks. Also, I am not aware of a debugger for opengl calls. As far as I am aware, you have to check for opengl errors manually.

Comment: And after the loop is exited? It should not be hard to look at the call stack when the program is in the "hang" state.

Comment: @derhass you where right there. It is the `glGetError()` getting stuck as it is calling the destructor for BufferObjects.

Comment: @derhass I have found the problem. Thanks for your help. I have posted a full answer and how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @derhass I have found the issue. I believe I understand the issue. The problem occurred with `glGetError()`. It was called when the program was being shut down and everything was being destructed. In the destructor, `GLCall()` was being used to make should the calls there worked correctly. The problem occurred because the destructors where being called after glfw was terminated, so the window context was destroyed. This means that every time I would call `glGetError` to clear the error tags that in itself would create another error tag.

The solution is to make sure that the buffers and program go out of scope before terminating glfw, which can be done with a set of curly brackets with the end bracket before `glfwTerminate()`.
Like below...

```
    {
     //...buffers and program variables here

     while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window.getWindow()))
        {
            GLCall(glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT));
            vertexBuffer.bind();
            indexBuffer.bind();
            shader.bind();
            shader.setUniformMat4("projection", projection);
            shader.setUniformMat4("translation", translation);

        GLCall(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
        GLCall(glfwSwapBuffers(window.getWindow()));

        GLCall(glfwPollEvents());
        }
    }
glfwTerminate();
```

Comment: I'm glad you found it. But... see how many comments were out of scope, were just guessings. This is a proof of a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always preferred.

Answer (score -1):

Not an OpenGL programmer, but my guess is `Engine::clearGLError();`

My shot in the dark is that it is clearly out valid context allowing `glfwWindowShouldClose` to return the correct value.